# Angular2: Straightforward injection token not resolved

Tags: angular

I've an `InjectionToken` available into a third-party library (`@living/cest`): `BASE_PATH`.

I want to use it only for printing it out on console.

I've declared the provider as:

```
import { BASE_PATH } from '@living/cest';
PROVIDERS = [
  { provide: BASE_PATH, useValue: 'http://guest1:8080/commty/cmng' }
];
```

So, into my `AppModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [ App ],
  declarations: [ App, ...],
  imports: [...],
  providers: [
    PROVIDERS
  ]
})
export class AppModule {...}
```

Into my `App` component:

```
import { BASE_PATH } from '@living/cest';

@Component({...})
export class App {
  constructor(@Optional()@Inject(BASE_PATH) private basePath: string) {
    console.info("BASEPATH: " + basePath);
  }
}
```

Nervertheless, the console output is:

> BASEPATH: null

**EDIT**

I'm using an `environment.ts` file in order to setting `PROVIDERS` array:

So, I onlt import it on `app.module.ts`:

```
import { ENV_PROVIDERS } from './environment';
```

and I'm using it strightforwardly:

```
providers: [
  ...PROVIDERS
]
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is that `PROVIDERS` is an array itself, which you pass into `providers`. Try to use `{..., providers: PROVIDERS}`

Comment: Another approach would be `{..., providers: [...PROVIDERS]}`

Comment: Mmm, I've tried with `providers: [...PROVIDERS]` and it keeps failing.

Comment: And what if you do your injections like this: `private basePath: BASE_PATH` Will it log something then?

Comment: Do you need the `@Optional()` decorator? Have you tried removing it?

Comment: I've tested with `private basePath: BASE_PATH`. ts is getting me a compilation error: `Cannot find name 'BASE_PATH'`.

Comment: Well that means the provider is not registered successfully. Remove the `@Optional()`. The issue lies somewhere in the `AppModule` and registration of the provider.

Comment: If I remove `@Optional`, it's getting me an `No provider for InjectionToken basePath!`

Comment: Yes, and as long as this error is shown when you remove the decorator, your code won't work.

Comment: So, why the registration has not worked?

Comment: I've tried it setting the provider directly on `AppModule` instead of using the `PROVIDERS` or `...PROVIDERS` array syntax and it's worked. So, I mean using this notation `providers: [
    { provide: BASE_PATH, useValue: 'http://guest1:8080/commty/cmng' }]` works... Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you didn't import or export your `PROVIDERS` constant correctly. Depending on where you defined it.

Comment: I've edited the post. What's strange on the way I'm using  and importing `PROVIDERS` array?